# Characterization of locally conformally flat manifolds with Frobenius theorem

Tags: riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry

In *Hamilton's Ricci Flow* (by Chow, Lu, Ni, pp. 29-31, see [here](https://books.google.it/books?id=T1K5fHoRalYC&pg=PA29)) they show that a Riemannian manifold $(M^n,g)$ is **locally conformally flat** iff the Weyl tensor vanishes
(when $n\ge 4$) and iff the Cotton tensor vanishes (when $n=3$).

In the proof they correctly say that it suffices to be able to find a $1$-form $X$ which solves
$$ \nabla_i X_j=b_{ij}+X_i X_j-\frac{1}{2}|X|^2 g_{ij}, $$
where $b_{ij}:=\frac{1}{n-2}\left(Ric_{ij}-\frac{1}{2(n-1)}Rg_{ij}\right)$.

Then they appeal to Frobenius theorem and state that it suffices to check that
$$ \nabla_k c_{ij}-\nabla_j c_{ik}=-R_{kij}^\ell X_\ell,\ \ \ (*) $$
where $c_{ij}:=b_{ij}+X_iX_j-\frac{1}{2}|X|^2 g_{ij}$, and they proceed by substituting $X$ and $\nabla X$ in order to check $(*)$.

Now to me **this makes no sense**: what does $(*)$ mean, since we don't know the existence of $X$ yet? How can one substitute $X$ and $\nabla X$ to check a condition *before* knowing that $X$ exists?

How can this be fixed in order to make sense?

Alternatively, any reference for a good proof is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you are only solving the equation for $X_j$'s in a chart. You have n variables and a priori $n^3$ equations. But the system is symmetric with respect to i,j ... so the number of equations reduce to $n^2$ . It takes a little bit more work to show that the system is also symmetric w.r.t. i and k. So eventually, you'll end up with n equations and n variables. Now these are coefficients of a form so you can first solve the equation point-wise for any point $p$ in a nice coordinate system with $g_{ij}(p) = 0$ and $\partial_k g_{ij}(p) = 0$ and then check to see your solution is still functorial.  hope this helps a bit.